# Angular delete object at index in stepperArray

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-stepper

Before I make this API call I need to remove the product that contains a selectedPlan value of null. I am unsure as to why the below is not working. Do I need reassignment of stepper array before passing as parameter in startEnrollment()?

```
startEnrollment(stepperArray: MhnStartEnrollmentRequest[]) {
        stepperArray.forEach(value => {
          if (value.selectedPlan === null) {
            delete stepperArray[value.productId]
          }
        });
        stepperArray.values();
        return this.mhnApiClientService.startEnrollment(stepperArray, this.quoteId, this.clientId);
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your accessing product to delete by `value.productId` instead of its actual index in the array

And instead of deleting it which just makes the value at that index `undefined` use `filter`

```
const enrolmentsWithAPlan = stepperArray.filter(value => value.selectedPlan !== null);
```

Comment: @Kokku Sivarama Akhilesh I have marked your answer as correct, can you please upvote the questions. Thanks